# How do I enable Big Picture Mode?

Tags: steam

Steam officially released [Big Picture Mode](http://store.steampowered.com/bigpicture/) today, for navigating Steam with a controller.  They claim it can be used from the computer, without the need to hook up to a TV.

But, **how do I do it?**  I've looked over all the menus and settings, and don't see anything for Big Picture Mode anywhere!

Comment: Why the close vote?  Just because you think it's obvious doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do'h!  Looks like I just needed to restart Steam *(even though I had already gotten the update...)*

Then the "Big Picture Mode" button is hard to miss - it's in the upper-right of the Steam UI.

[image: Steam UI]

Comment: It can also be launched directly from the Notification Tray icon (on Windows). Presumably there is some command line switch as well.